# how to test an observable in service

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-test

I'm creating a unit test for my service:

```
private _element$: BehaviorSubject<string>;

element$: Observable<string>;

constructor() {

  this.element$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('test');
  this.element$ = this._element$.asObservable();
}
```

And the test for it is

```
let service;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
    ],
   });

  service = new TestService();
 });

 it('should give next object',
   async() =>{
     expect(service._element$.getValue()).toEqual('test') -> works
     service.element$.subscribe(element =>
          expect(element.toEqual('test')
     ) -> fails
 });
```

The observable fails because "undefined is not a function". If I debug I can see that it can't finde "service".

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Where and how do you instantiate service? It wouldn't came from the air.

Answer (score 1):

The test body should be parameter to `async` function, and there are some typos:

```
it('should give next object',
   async(() => {
     expect(service.element$.getValue()).toEqual('test');
     service.element$.subscribe(element =>
          expect(element).toEqual('test')
     );
 }));
```

Comment: thanks but I got the same error "undefined is not a function", could it be because it is because it is a string?

Comment: on which line? `expect(element).toEqual('test')` here? have you correct imports?

Answer (score 0):

try adding a filter (from rxjs) before .subscribe

```
service.element$
.pipe(filter(el => !!el ))
.subscribe(element =>
    expect(element.toEqual('test');
)
```